# Why Counter component rendered two times?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-dream-optcq) I have an example. Why in `Counter` component `renderRadioGroup` rendered two times in mount or even in every change(i.e, increase/decrease/radio selection)?

Example includes a counter with increase/decrease/set actions such that its state stored in redux and Counter component uses `useCallback` hook to cache internal functions.

You can see number of renders in console.

Answer (score -1):

what ever that is your return is rendered first then after the component is mounted is another rendering.

default value is returned then after the component is mounted ( the data is fetched and updated hence second rendering )

Comment: I do not understand your answer, please explain more clearly(which component? `render` of which component? for which action and which order?). Q: If I push `increase` why `renderRadioGroup` rendered two times? and so on...